# Telegram bot - telegraf vs telebot

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram

I am looking to make a bot using telegram api, so I found two good apis in nodejs but I couldn't find the difference between them:

1. TeleGraf
2. TeleBot

What is the difference and why should I prefer one over the other? Or should I use another API to do a bot in telegram?

Thank you

Comment: what is your preferred language?

Comment: Just came into this question since I was also looking for some kind of recommendation on each of them.
Am I missing somethings why his language wouldn't be javascript? he tagged `node.js` and both of the options he gave are written in javascript

Answer (score 2):

The official [sample section for node.js](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples#node-js) contains a list of (somewhat) popular options.

> Telegraf. Full Telegram Bot API support, including games and inline mode.

In my perspective, Telegraf is a more complete & active library. And is thus likely to receive more timely updates when the API changes, in the end it all depends on your use-case though; but Telegraf should have you covered in most(/all) cases.

On the other hand, Telebot might take an approach that's simpler to use for you; so it all depends on your personal opinion in the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is question about your language :)
As is known, TeleGraf uses js (ts) and TeleBot uses python
For js you can also use node-telegram-bot-api from **yagop**

Comment: 1. telegraf uses js, not ts (if referred to typescript). 2. tele**b**ot is for node.js, tele**p**ot is for python